# JavaFX: How do you call and pass the control object?

Tags: java, javafx

This is a method for getting the text of different JavaFx controls.

```
private String getText(Node item) {
        
    String txt = "";

    if (item instanceof Label) {
        if(!((Label)item).getText().isEmpty()){
            txt = ((Label)item).getText();
        }
    }
    if (item instanceof TextField) {
        if(!((TextField)item).getText().isEmpty()){
            txt = ((TextField)item).getText();
        }
    }
    if (item instanceof CheckBox) {
        if(!((CheckBox)item).getText().isEmpty()){
            txt = ((CheckBox)item).getText();
        }
    }
    return txt;
}
```

I'm trying to lessen the lines of codes. Instead of defining Label, TextField, CheckBox, etc. Is there an object class that I could call for all other controls and put in beside the Node item so that I don't need to repeat and specify each control? Is there a way to make it like this?

```
private String getText(Node item, X x) {

    String txt = "";

    if (item instanceof x) {
        if(!((x)item).getText().isEmpty()){
            txt = ((x)item).getText();
        }
    return txt;
}
```

What should I replace X & x. I don't know what object should I call or replace the Control. Just don't mind about the logic of isEmpty. My main concern is what object should I call or replace the Control.
And call the method like this

```
getText(txtSample, TextField.class)
```

or

```
getText(lblSample, Label.class)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the common superclass Control has no method `getText()` (because not all controls have text), this is not possible.

EDIT: as James_D pointed out, `Label` and `CheckBox` *do* have a common ancestor that has the method `getText()`, namely `Labeled`. This saves us another `instanceof` check.

However, the rest of the similarities can be extracted. Suppose we first write a helper method to extract the text from the control (note the down casting in the same statement as the `instanceof`:

```
    private String getRawText( final Node item )
    {
        if( item instanceof Labeled labeled )
            return labeled.getText();
        else if( item instanceof TextField field )
            return field.getText();
        else //this is the default
            return "";
    }
```

then the original function becomes:

```
    private String getText( final Node item ) 
    {

        final var  txt = getRawText( item );

        return txt.isEmpty() 
                ? ""
                : txt;
    }
```

But note that you check `text.isEmpty()` while the default, with which you initialized the variable `txt` is itself empty  (`""`). Thus the check for empty is not needed. Did you mean `.isBlank()` (stripping whitespace only strings)? Or `getText() == null`?

Otherwise, it can be removed, and then your left with the function `getRawText()` only.

Comment: Note you can capture both `Label` and `CheckBox` (and other controls) with `if (item instanceof Labeled labeled) return labeled.getText();`